# wp-ecommerce product links going to the wrong url

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, permalinks

Hi I recently installed wp-ecommerce on a site i am working on. I had previously tried to change the page that the shop appears on by creating a new page and copying the shortcode from the original 'products-page' to my new page 'our-products'. Pretty pointless i realise now. I decided against this and just used the original page - but now when i go to 'products page' everything including the checkout etc works perfectly except when you click on a product to view it on its own page. it jumps to domain/our-products/... and the page is broken.

I tried to change all the settings in wp-options to the original page but it makes no difference. I went into phpmyadmin and found references to the 'our-products' eg the wrong page in the wp-options table. If i change these to the correct page should it work?

What is also weird though is when I delete the 'our-products' page the entire store stops working.

Here is the site product page: http://www.nuvogadgets.com/products-page/

Here is what happens when you click on a product: http://www.nuvogadgets.com/our-products/product-category/test-product/

Cheers Paul

Comment: I have been experiencing a similar thing. I ended up removing the category it was associated with, and got left with `uncategorized`

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup(!) and then install the [Store Toolkit from Visser Labs](http://www.visser.com.au/wp-ecommerce/plugins/store-toolkit/), and relink broken pages from that.